# Fixing a sagging shower door that can't easily be removed

Tags: doors, shower

I have a sagging shower door, but I can't easily remove it to tighten things up. The top screw (of two) is right next to the shower unit. I've tried using a right angled screwdriver to tighten it, but I can't get it to move.

Is the fix for this as simple as putting some wedges under the door, drilling a new hole and adding another screw? Is it possible to put a nut on the inside of the vertical rail, or is that not required?

[image: Screw that just won't turn]
[image: Very lopsided door]

Comment: Where's this screw? No matter how much I push it in photoshop, this black blob does not resolve to a screw-head - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEj7Z.jpg It's also almost impossible to tell what's sagging or where.

Comment: So...remove the shower unit?

Comment: :facepalm: That's a cover over the screw.

Comment: Is that the answer to your question - pop the cover off then tighten the screw? If so, please write that up in the "Answer" box below and click the check mark when the system will allow you to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn off the water & electricity supply to the shower unit and lift the cover off.

Then, disconnect the water supply and release the fixings holding the shower. Move it as needed, sort the door and refit.

Comment: Fair enough. That seemed like a lot more work, but it's possibly less likely to go horribly wrong